# How do I connect to mySQL database as a (Windows) client?

Tags: mysql, windows

Okay, I am not dumb just ignorant. I have got mySQL Server working and am able to connect to my database with ADO on the server. Now I am trying to connect from a client computer. After searching and reading MANY Google hits (most from Stack Overflow) I finally concluded that the only easy path to this is to install the whole huge mySQL server package on the client computer (installing just the Client option fails completely).

But with this mess I can only connect to the same schema on the client computer; that is, it is just acting like a server and not connecting to my server-side database at all.  How do I do it? I would love to just install something thin on the client side, but nobody seems to be telling how to do it for Windows. I am willing to keep the bloated server install on the clients because I am desperate, but how do I do that?

Comment: What do you want to do on the client? Directly query and update the data as user?

Comment: Clients need to have fairly wide permissions, so I'm just (trying to) log on as root. At least create/delete tables, add/delete records, update records and query. This is personal stuff on my LAN so I don't care about security or wide permissions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect with various tools. I suggest starting with MySQLWorkbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

If you want to connect from code, you need only have the proper library for the language you are coding in. They are called mySQL connectors. You can find them here (https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/). With the connector in your app, you can make api calls to connect to and access the database.

Comment: That's the problem ... I have the connector I need (DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}), but that's not sufficient (according to endless trying, searching and reading) because I also need at least the service mysqld.exe ... to get this working at all I need to install the entire mySQL bloatware ... so I've got everything, just can't connect. I need to connect with ADO, and I have that working perfectly on the server side, it's just failing on the client side as described in OP.

Comment: That's not the case. mysqld is not required on the client. You do not need to install anything except the ODBC connector. Link your app against the DLLs included with it and you will be fine. Did you run the connector and setup a connection to your database server?

Comment: Ok I love your post because it's the first sane-sounding thing I've heard or read on this subject in several days ... I will install only the connector on a fresh box tomorrow morning and try again, but I'm sure my attempt will fail as before, my ignorance is blocking success. I'm using the same ADO connection string on the client that works on the server: ADOConnection_mySQL.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & "SERVER=127.0.0.1;" & "PORT=3306" & "DATABASE=g:\$dbase\spx_opts;" & "UID=root;" & "PWD=speen;" & "Option=3" ... is there anything obviously wrong with this?

Comment: the server address should not be "127.0.0.1". That's the loop back address and refers to the local machine. It should be the address of the machine where the  mysql server is running.

Comment: Awesome, thanks John, I'm up and running ... just needed to use the correct IP address, plus needed to install the 32-bit driver because I'm connecting via 32-but Excel.  I'm new to stack overflow, so let me know if there is something I'm supposed to do to close this question and give you the credit ...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [SQuirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/). It works with the major database management systems. [This](http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=screenshots) is how to configure a connection. You need a [MySQL JDBC-driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). It a jar-file. I simply dropped it in the `lib`-directory of SQuirrel SQL.

An alternative to SQuirrel SQL for MySQL is [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/).